# How we can access a needed protocol in other protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I was looking to **ViewModifier** protocol in SwiftUI I see the requirement of:

```
associatedtype Body: View
@ViewBuilder func body(content: Self.Content) -> Self.Body
typealias Content
```

Then I could not understand how even it is possible?! because we cannot reference Content to Self, simply it does not defined. How that code should build? I am 100% that I am missing something here but cannot find it. I see `typealias Content` in documentation, but as you can see it make no meaning for Xcode.

```
public protocol CustomViewModifier {

    associatedtype Body: View
    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Self.Content) -> Self.Body
    // typealias Content  // What should be Content here?
}
```

Error:

> 'Content' is not a member type of type 'Self'

So how can I define Content to my protocol like apple did for ViewModifier?

---

Update:

```
struct TestCustomViewModifier: CustomViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
    }
}
```

Error:

> Return type of instance method 'body(content:)' requires that 'TestCustomViewModifier.Content' (aka '_MyContent') conform to 'View'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like following:

```
public protocol CustomViewModifier {

    associatedtype Body: View
    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Self.Content) -> Self.Body
    typealias Content = _MyContent<Self>

}

public struct _MyContent<Modifier> where Modifier: CustomViewModifier {
}
```

The only difference is that underscored names in `SwiftUI` namespace, like `SwiftUI._ViewModifierContent` are hidden by Xcode as private API.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use your code, but I got a new issue, I add the issue as update.